# CollapsingToolbarLayout and FloatingActionButton

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and inside two `FloatingActionButtons`. These FABs are visible only when the `Toolbar` is expanded. When is collapsed, they are hidden. I need them visible, if toolbar is collapsed too. How can I do it?

Thanks a lot for tips...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".CalendarEventInsUpdActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_calendar_event"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a [Behavior](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html) to the FAB.

Try something similar to:

```
public class ScrollingFABBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton> {
    private int toolbarHeight;

    public ScrollingFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.toolbarHeight = Utils.getToolbarHeight(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton fab, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton fab, View dependency) {
        //do nothing with the fab or write your logic for the FAB
        return true;
    }
}
```

then add the behaviour using the XML FAB tag

```
app:layout_behavior="com.example.ScrollingFABBehavior" />
```

Comment: I chose @royB answer because with his solution I can affect FABs behavior in java code.

Answer (score 0):

you must insert Fabs as direct child of cordinatorLayout and use layout behavior, :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: use Layout_behaviors like mine

Answer (score 0):

try this xml.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">



            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_calendar_event"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```